# Python Gtk3 set text in textview

Tags: python, textview, gtk, gtk3

i can get richtext from textbuffer with this:

```
exported = self.textbuffer.serialize(
                         self.textbuffer,
                         self.textbuffer.register_serialize_tagset(),
                         start_iter,
                         end_iter
                         )
```

how can i set text into textBuffer?

Comment: If my answer worked, mark it as accepted, so people know that it worked.

Comment: Title states «g»et text but question is: how can i «s»et text. I think it must be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i somehow completly missed this in The docs .

http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.deserialize

> `deserialize (content_buffer, format, iter, data)`
>
> This function deserializes rich text in format format and inserts it at iter.  formats to be used must be registered using `Gtk.TextBuffer.register_deserialize_format()` or `Gtk.TextBuffer.register_deserialize_tagset()` beforehand.

Which is the answer i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple:

```
s = "string"
l = len(s)
self.textbuffer.set_text(s, l)
```

The [docs](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/TextBuffer.html#Gtk.TextBuffer.set_text) .

Comment: although technically correct, it's not what i asked for. in Gtk the `set_text(text, length=-1)` only supports UTF-8 encoding.